# Blinking cursor on black screen using Virtualbox

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu virtual machine on my Windows 10 laptop to do work on it. I've been following step by step tutorials, but when Ubuntu should boots and show me the desktop, I'm stuck with a blinking cursor on a black screen.

I've tried the `nomodeset` stuff and nothing is working. I've changed the Ubuntu ISO and that didn't work either.

I also tried with Vagrant, with a 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu, but both froze at `SSH auth method: private key`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a few informations.
I'm running on windows 10 64-bit,
Intel I7,

Comment: Does the login screen appear if you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 ? I've had this happen during OS version upgrades on VMs. Not posting as an answer as not sure it will work.

Comment: I can access some kind of menu yes. That's where I tried to activate the "nomodeset" and stuff

Comment: Is the menu you get the Grub menu? It'll say something like Grub 2.0 at the top of the screen if so. Are the SSH warnings just on the Vagrant setups?

Comment: According to OP's answer the issue was the disabled virtualization support in BIOS. I'm **voting to close as off topic** since that's entirely unrelated to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it. I had to turn on Intel VT-x in the BIOS options.

Comment: Click the checkmark beside your answer to accept it and give it a green checkmark.